# Eliminar nodo hoja de un árbol binario

Tags: php, estructuras-de-datos, árboles-binarios

Ayuda necesito eliminar un nodo hoja de un árbol binario

```
public function EliminarNodo($n,$dato){
   if($this->root !=null){
     if($n->getLeft() == null && $n->getRight()==null){
       if($n->getValor()==$dato){
         $n=null;
       }
     }else{
       $i=$this->EliminarNodo($n->getLeft(),$dato);
       if($i!= null){
         return $i;
       }else{
         $s=$this->MostrarHojas($n->getRight(),$dato);
         return $s; 
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Ey, Que tal amigo!

Acá tengo una clase con diferentes métodos para un Arbol de forma recursiva en Java, también esta el que necesitas. ¡Espero te sirva, Saludos!

```
public class Main {

    Arbol arbol;

    public Main(){
        arbol = null;
    }

    public void insertar(int valor) {
        arbol = insertarValor(arbol, valor);
    }


    public Arbol insertarValor(Arbol raizA, int valor) {

        if (raizA == null) {
            raizA = new Arbol(valor);
            System.out.println("Raiz " + raizA.getValor());
            return raizA;
        }

        if (valor < raizA.getValor()){
            System.out.println(" por la izquierda ");
            raizA.izq = insertarValor(raizA.getIzq(), valor);

        }else if (valor > raizA.getValor()){
            System.out.println("por la derecha");
            raizA.der = insertarValor(raizA.der, valor);
        }

        return raizA;
    }

    public Arbol eliminar(int valor){
        arbol = eliminarValor(arbol, valor);
        return arbol;
    }

    public Arbol eliminarValor(Arbol raizA, int valor){
        if (raizA == null){ 
            System.out.println("No se encuentra el valor " + valor + " en el arbol.");
            return raizA;
        }

        if(valor==raizA.valor){
            if (raizA.izq == null){
                System.out.println("Eliminado ");
                return raizA.der;
            }else if (raizA.der == null){
                System.out.println("Eliminado ");
                return raizA.izq;
            }

        }

        if (valor < raizA.valor){
            raizA.izq = eliminarValor(raizA.izq, valor);
        }else if (valor > raizA.valor){
            raizA.der= eliminarValor(raizA.der, valor);
        }

        return raizA;
    }



    public Arbol buscarValor(Arbol raizA, int valor){

        if (raizA==null){
            System.out.println("El valor " + valor + " no se encontró");
            return raizA;
        }

        if(raizA.valor==valor){
            System.out.println("El valor " + valor + " se encontró");
            return raizA;
        }

        if (raizA.valor > valor){
                System.out.println("El valor " + valor + " esta por el lado izquierdo de la raiz " + raizA.valor);
                return buscarValor(raizA.izq, valor);
        }else if(raizA.valor < valor){
                System.out.println("El valor " + valor + " esta por el lado derecho de la raiz " + raizA.valor);
                return buscarValor(raizA.der,valor);
        }
        return null;

    }



    public static void main(String []args){
        Main ar = new Main();

        ar.insertar(5);
        ar.insertar(10);
        ar.insertar(20);
        ar.insertar(15);
        ar.insertar(30);
        ar.insertar(3);
        ar.insertar(100);


        ar.eliminar(3);
        ar.eliminar(100);
        ar.eliminar(100);

        ar.buscarValor(ar.arbol,30);

    }

}
```

Comment: Julian Perez, muchas gracias me fue de mucha ayuda